# running process command line

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the command line of running processes in Windows using the code below:
But I only get the command line of `IDman.exe` like this:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe" /onboot`

But I know there are many other processes with command lines.

Give any idea what's wrong with my code.

```
PVOID GetPebAddress(HANDLE ProcessHandle )
{
    _NtQueryInformationProcess NtQueryInformationProcess =
             (_NtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(
             GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;

    NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle, 0, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL);

   return pbi.PebBaseAddress;
}

void get_process_cmd_line(DWORD pID)
     {

       HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                     PROCESS_VM_READ |
                                     PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                                     FALSE, pID);
       PPEB ppeb = (PPEB) GetPebAddress(hProcess);
       PPEB ppebCopy = (PPEB)malloc(sizeof(PEB));
       BOOL result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                                       ppeb,
                                       ppebCopy,
                                       sizeof(PEB),
                                       NULL);
       if(!result){std::cout<<"Er. adress";return;}
       PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS pRtlProcParam = ppebCopy->ProcessParameters;
       PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS pRtlProcParamCopy =
          (PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS)malloc(sizeof(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS));
       result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                                  pRtlProcParam,
                                  pRtlProcParamCopy,
                                  sizeof(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS),
                                  NULL);
       if(!result){std::cout<<"Er. ";return;}
       PWSTR wBuffer = pRtlProcParamCopy->CommandLine.Buffer;
       USHORT len = pRtlProcParamCopy->CommandLine.Length;
       PWSTR wBufferCopy = (PWSTR)malloc(len);
       result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                                  wBuffer,
                                  wBufferCopy, 
                                  len,NULL);
       if(!result){std::cout<<"Er. cmdLine";return;}
       std::wcout<<wBufferCopy;
       return;
}
```

Comment: Edit  : i noticed just now that when the get_process_cmd_line(DWORD pID)  succeeds in getting the command line of a process it can't succeed anymore !!!

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you want to achieve, and why this way. Why can't you use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?

Whatsoever the motive, and approach, I suggest you to do thorough checking for failure with each function call (starting from `OpenProcess`). Read the documentation on what a particular function returns on failure, or success. Always use `GetLastError` to determine the exact reason (or any other relevant function mentioned in MSDN).

Are you running, or willing to run your program as a service? If not, why can't you do step-by-step debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Your current process has probably not enough rights to read other's process memory. Try running the process as administrator.

The code itself looks basically OK.

Comment: yes i did run as administrator but same results and almost all processes  return the "Er. adress " ...